Using outputs from one module for another module in azurerm
Ok.. so..
I have an issue where main.tf calls one module (appservice.tf) which has an output that is then relied upon by another module (roleassignment.tf)
In my case... from main.tf I call my appservice.tf
module "contractreview_apibackendappservice" {
  source = "./appservice"
  app_service_plan_id = module.appserviceplan.app_service_plan_id
  resource_group_name = module.vnet.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
  app_service_name = "zettle-${var.environment_name}-contracts-api"
  subnet_id = module.vnet.defaultsubnet_id
}

appservice.tf code here below, we create a managed identity
resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "appservice" {
  name                = var.app_service_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  service_plan_id     = var.app_service_plan_id
  https_only          = true
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  site_config {
    http2_enabled = true
    websockets_enabled = true
    always_on = true
    vnet_route_all_enabled = true
    use_32_bit_worker = false    
  }
  virtual_network_subnet_id = var.subnet_id
}

appservice.tf output variable:
output "principal_id_of_managed_identity" {
  value = azurerm_windows_web_app.appservice.identity[0].principal_id
}

Back in main.tf I reference that variable
locals {
  rows_for_storage_account = [
    {
      role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
      principal_id = module.contractreview_apibackendappservice.principal_id_of_managed_identity
    },
    {
      role_definition_name = "Storage Queue Data Contributor"
      principal_id = module.contractreview_apibackendappservice.principal_id_of_managed_identity
    }     
  ]
}

module "roleassignment_for_api_storage" {
  source = "./roleassignment"

  for_each = { for row in local.rows_for_storage_account : "${row.role_definition_name}-${row.principal_id}" => row }

  scope = module.storageaccount.storage_account_id
  role_definition_name = each.value.role_definition_name
  principal_id_of_managed_identity_to_give_role_assignment_to = each.value.principal_id
  app_service_name = module.contractreview_apibackendappservice.app_service_name
  depends_on = [ module.contractreview_apibackendappservice ]
}

But it errors when terraform plan runs.. roleassignment module is looking for the value of the principal id that hasn't been established yet.
│ Error: Invalid template interpolation value

│   on main.tf line 138, in module "roleassignment_for_api_storage":

│  138:   for_each = { for row in local.rows_for_storage_account : "${row.role_definition_name}-${row.principal_id}" => row }

│     │ row.principal_id is null

│ The expression result is null. Cannot include a null value in a string template.

How can I get the roleassignment module to only run once the principal_id_of_managed_identity is established / known?
I know I can do one terraform plan/apply to get the managed principal set up / established and then uncomment the roleassignment module and run a second plan/apply for the role assignment creation but this is obviously a hack of the highest order. This works but clearly sucks.
I guess, I need some sort of way to create a dependency between the two? Currently terraform isn't recognising the dependency on it's own or the fact that the principal id is to be established when the apply is run.
I'm using azurerm 3.100.0 if that's relevant
Thanks :)

Why wouldn't  principal id be established? Does it take time for azure to establish it, but terraform does not wait for when this happens?

turns out on a new app service with SystemAssigned identity set from the start this was fine, azurerm struggles / errors when adding SystemAssigned onto an existing app service and giving role assignments at the same time. yuk!


Using outputs from one module for another module in azurerm

The roleassignment module need to be dependent on managed identity in setting up appservice module. Here to achieve this requirement we need to make sure the terraform actions need to wait till the availability of principal_id.
To achieve this requirement, we need to use null_resource. In reference to for_each with dynamic values and depends_on tried a configuration which works successfully without any blocker.
Terraform configuration:
main.tf:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

module "appserviceplan" {
  source = "./appserviceplan"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  app_service_plan_name = "appserviceplan-${var.environment_name}"
}

module "vnet" {
  source              = "./vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  vnet_name           = "vnet-${var.environment_name}"
  vnet_address_space  = var.vnet_address_space
  subnet_name         = "subnet-${var.environment_name}"
  subnet_prefix       = var.subnet_prefix
}

module "contractreview_apibackendappservice" {
  source                = "./appservice"
  app_service_plan_id   = module.appserviceplan.app_service_plan_id
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  app_service_name      = "zettle-${var.environment_name}-contracts-api"
  subnet_id             = module.vnet.defaultsubnet_id
}

resource "null_resource" "role_assignment_trigger" {
  depends_on = [module.contractreview_apibackendappservice]
}

locals {
  role_assignments = [
    {
      role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
      principal_id = module.contractreview_apibackendappservice.principal_id_of_managed_identity
    },
    {
      role_definition_name = "Storage Queue Data Contributor"
      principal_id = module.contractreview_apibackendappservice.principal_id_of_managed_identity
    }     
  ]
}

module "roleassignment_for_api_storage" {
  source = "./roleassignment"

  role_assignments = local.role_assignments
  scope            = module.storageaccount.storage_account_id

  depends_on = [null_resource.role_assignment_trigger]
}

module "storageaccount" {
  source = "./storageaccount"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = var.location

}

variable.tf:
variable "location" {
  description = "The location where resources will be created"
  type        = string
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "environment_name" {
  description = "The environment name"
  type        = string
}

variable "vnet_address_space" {
  description = "The address space of the virtual network"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

variable "subnet_prefix" {
  description = "The subnet prefix"
  type        = string
  default     = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

roleassignment/main.tf:
variable "role_assignments" {
  description = "The list of roles and principal IDs for role assignment"
  type        = list(object({
    role_definition_name = string
    principal_id         = string
  }))
}

variable "scope" {
  description = "The scope at which the role assignment applies"
  type        = string
}
    
   
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "roleassignment" {
  for_each = { for idx, val in var.role_assignments : idx => val }

  scope                = var.scope
  role_definition_name = each.value.role_definition_name
  principal_id         = each.value.principal_id
}

and continue with the module configuration of rest of the resources like App service, storage and Vnet etc.
deployment succeeded:




@Andrew Duffy Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
